# Working at a company that expects you to quit before a large raise

Tags: salary, negotiation

All the research I have done online says that you should never quit your job on the hope of getting a salary increase. Even if one does the get the desired raise, things are never the [same](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/150174/38113).

However, is it possible that the CEO expects notice to be given before going above the normal raise. I have talked to ex colleagues and every one of them has been asked if they would stay for more money or been offered more money. Nobody has taken these offers.

Again, this goes against everything that I found online. Is there some CEO manual that recommends this tactic? Should I call the bluff? I am convinced, this is his modus operandi but will things "be different" after?

Also, this question is not 100% related to having another job offer received. The scenario might mean the employee has time to get another job or even is interested in some extended time off. I am aware that I don't have to tell my employer any other reasons for leaving.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/150167/79019

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Source: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/150174/38113

Answer (score 4):

The point is these companies don't expect you to quit to get a raise - they expect you to stay forever without a raise, and when someone leaves they are surprised and offer a raise.

Of course they know what they are doing, and you should know they know what they are doing. So if you think you should have received a raise and didn't, then you look for a better job quietly without telling anyone, and when you have a legally binding offer for a better paying job in hand, then you give the legally required amount of notice and don't look back.

If you get a counter offer remember that they didn't want to pay you in the first place. The raise you would get would be the last one ever. Or they might break their promise of a raise once you refused the new offer. Or they break their promise and fire you once you refused the new offer. That has happened.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are on the money here. However, I am not so sure about the sentence "the raise you would get would be the last one ever". Is this generally true?

Comment: Of course. You showed them that you can leave, _and_ you increased their cost, so they will get rid of you and replace you with someone cheaper as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe.
You will find a lot of advice that says never accept this.
If money is the only reason you quit, it could work out for you. if there are other factors that make you quit, those should change too!
But I know several people who got counter offers after quiting.
In my last company, there was a time of financial trouble. Then people started quiting a lot. And a lot of those people got counter offers. Some stayed. Some are still in the company to this day!

I don't really know a lot of people who stayed and regretted this. But I think this is a bias, because if people think staying is bad, they will just go through with quitting. And often, their hunches are right.

This depends a lot upon general company culture. Did you talk to people who stayed how it worked out for them?
This will be your best indicator.

Answer (score 0):

There are **very few guarantees** in life.  What guarantee do you have that they will make a counter offer if you resign?  They may very well accept your resignation without any dismay, and that may leave you without a job, specially since you don't have any other legally binding offers.  If that happens and you retract your resignation, assuming the company allows it, you will be the one with ice-cream on your face.

If your salary is the only reason you are considering this, rather schedule a meeting with your superiors and ask about reviewing your salary. **Be prepared** for this meeting and **have numbers ready** of what market value for someone in your position with your experience is in your area.  Also be ready to hear "No." too.

Once you have had your meeting, you will know where you stand and can plan your next step accordingly.